# Time Based IP Block with MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using ajax to store votes and currently trying to give every IP Adresse that has already voted a Block for 18 hours.

First I'm storing the IP and Time in the database but I can't seem to figure out how I check if the IP is found in my array and then if the time associated to the Ip is the matching with 18hours plus.

I am using a multidimensional array for each row in my database.
This is what I have so far, but I am always getting either a 500 or unexpected end of JSON error.

```
 $currentip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $time  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $exptime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+18 Hours'));

    // Check IP
    $sqlip = "SELECT ip,exptime FROM `user_ip` ;";
    $storedip = array();
     if ($result = $this->databaseConnection->query($sqlip)){
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $storedip = array($row['ip'], $row['exptime']);
            }       

      if(in_array($currentip, array_column($storedip, '0'))){
      $key = array_search($currentip, array_column($storedip, 0));

        if($time <= $storedip[$key][1]){
            echo json_encode("IP Block active", JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
         }
      } 
      else{

         $setip = "INSERT INTO `user_ip` VALUES ('$currentip','$exptime');";
          if($this->executeDatabaseQuery($setip)){
        // Count Vote and do my stuff
          }
         }
     }
```

Comment: don't fetch the entire table and then use `in_array` to see if they already voted... you're needlessly returning a crapton of data and then doing an `O(n)` search on it when you could do it directly in MySQL in like `log n`.

Comment: I am only storing IP and Time in this table.. How would I do it in MySQL?

Comment: `select exists(select * from user_ip where ip=:ip and exptime > now())` assuming `exptime` is when they're allowed to vote again. if that returns 1 then they've already voted and their timer isn't up yet.

Comment: @mpen so I don't even have to store all the values in php because MySQL does that by itself? Can I just use an if condition with that Query and see if it returns 1 or not in PHP?

Comment: I wouldn't say "by itself". You're inserting all the records into the database, so yeah...they're in the database. You don't need to fetch every record every time you want to check for existence. And yes...you can put that in an `if` condition. With PDO you'd want to use `->fetchColumn()` to fetch a single value. You're using mysqli it looks like? You'll have to find the equivalent function -- you don't need `fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$storedip = array($row['ip'], $row['exptime']);
```

It should be:

```
$storedip[] = array($row['ip'], $row['exptime']);
```

Comment: This may do but I feel the question deserves an explanation rather than just dropping code and saying "it should be". IMHO of course.

Comment: Well, yea  it works!! Thank you. I'm just learning PHP and MySQL and I'm happy for an explanation.

Comment: There, you see? ^ many like to know the reason ;-) including the OP.

Comment: `$storedip[] =` appends to the array. `$storedip =` assigns/overwrites the value entirely. in either case, this is not a good solution.